# Achievements / Reset

Tags: facebook, reset, achievements

We're implementing some achievements for our game so we're working on our QA app.

How can I reset (if at all) all the achievements in the app ?

Comment: If you're storing achievements in a database, how about truncating the achievements table?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the achievements via the API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/achievements/

Comment: Thanks, I've found the specific delete - but it does not allow to delete if a user has that achievement. So a bit of a hassle which I'll gladly avoid (NOTE: I know it's against fb policy to delete, this is in a QA app)